# Vim print diagnostic message into message buffer AND prevent "press Enter to continue" prompt

Tags: vim

I'm trying to improve the [vim indentfinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=513) script (which I am hosting as a fork [here](https://github.com/unphased/Vim-IndentFinder)), and what I'd like is for the plugin to place an entry in the message log about what it detected for the indentation of the current buffer, but I do not want it to hang up the opening of the file with that annoying green "Press ENTER or type command to continue..." prompt, because the user will not care about this little message, the user will only usually want to look at it after-the-fact, if the indentation of the opened file was detected incorrectly, etc.

How to do this?

```
silent !echom
```

prevents the message from making its way into the message buffer.

```
echo
```

never makes its way into the buffer *and* triggers the press enter prompt.

I tried to chain a `| normal ^M` after the `echom` call, in hopes of sending the Enter key to dismiss the prompt, but this does not work.

Comment: why not write those info to a log file, if they are really important? say [yourplugin.log]

Comment: No they are not that important at all!

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is cool.

I looked at this documentation:

```
                                         :echo-redraw         
         A later redraw may make the message disappear again. 
         And since Vim mostly postpones redrawing until it's  
         finished with a sequence of commands this happens    
         quite often.  To avoid that a command from before the
         ":echo" causes a redraw afterwards (redraws are often
         postponed until you type something), force a redraw  
         with the :redraw command.  Example: 

         :new | redraw | echo "there is a new window"
```

The undesired prompting is really Vim trying to be nice, so if we just tell it what we want, everyone's happy!

Applied it to the plugin (`redraw | echom ...`) and it works a charm.